# Plot only shows if closing main window from Tkinter with .exe

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pyinstaller, py2exe

I've created an application which after choosing some files and clicking a specific button, it generates 3 to 5 plots using matplotlib (and some uses plotly). For this GUI I used Tkinter.

When I run the .py code it works perfectly, after pressing the button a plot is shown, then after closing its window a new one is displayed and so on until finish.

I tried creating the .exe file for this application using Py2exe and PyInstaller. Both of them have the same behaviour: after pressing the button the first plot is shown, but when I close its window no one is displayed. Only after closing the Tkinter windows created (one main Frame that creates another Frame which has the buttons I click for displaying the plot) the other plots appear (the second one, then after closing its window the third one, and so on).

Any clue about this? I've tried also

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

without success. TkAgg is the one that worked for generating the .exe (had to change it in the matplotlibrc).

The code runs the following way: main_app with Tkinter functionalities, second_app with some useful functions and only one Tkinter message (if conditions satisfied) and a bunch of minor .py files that each one is a function with its own calculations and plots.

If a button from the main_app is pressed it calls one specific of these minor .py files (functions) for calculating and generating the plots.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I was using Python 3.4 and PyInstaller 3.3, and I would try to make several plots at once but only one would show until I closed the whole executable (made with PyInstaller's --onefile option). I solved the problem by using

```
 plt.show(block=False)
```

instead of

```
plt.show()
```

when plotting. This did the trick for me, hope it helps you!